# Logrotate of /var/log/messages files

Tags: rotation, logrotate, log-rotation, pm2-logrotate, logrocket

How can I set log rotate to, /var/log/messages files,
all the files with the name "messages",
rotate every 4 days (to keep last 4 files),
not to generate any error messages??

/var/log/messsages-* {
dateext
maxage 3
rotate 4
missingok
nocompress
}

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless you are moving the files out of that directory with the `olddir` directive, you should never end your regex path with a wildcard:

> Please use wildcards with caution. If you specify *, logrotate will
> rotate all files, including previously rotated ones. A way around this
> is to use the olddir directive or a more exact wildcard (such as
> *.log).

You will end up with an infinitely-repeating cycle of rotations. You do not need a wildcard at all in your directive definition.